# HBase 0.98.1 Put operations never timeout

Tags: timeout, hbase

I am using 0.98.1 version of HBase server and client. My application has strict response time requirements. As far as HBase is concerned, I would like to abort the HBase operation if the execution exceeds 1 or 2 seconds. This task timeout is useful in case of Region-Server being non-responsive or has crashed.

```
 I tired configuring
    1) HBASE_RPC_TIMEOUT_KEY = "hbase.rpc.timeout";
    2) HBASE_CLIENT_RETRIES_NUMBER = "hbase.client.retries.number";
```

However, the Put operations never timeout (I am using sync flush). The operations return only after the Put is successful.

I looked through the code and found that the function receiveGlobalFailure in AsyncProcess class keeps resubmitting the task without any check on the retires. This is in version 0.98.1

I do see that in 0.99.1 there have been some changes to AsyncProcess class that might do what I want. I have not verified it though.

My questions are:

1. Is there any other configuration that I missed that can give me
   the desired functionality.
2. Do I have to use 0.99.1 client to
       solve my problem? Does 0.99.1 solve my problem?
3. If I have to use 0.99.1 client, then do I have to use 0.99.1 server or can I still use my existing 0.98.1 region-server.